# Login and get secret from hashicorp vault in nodejs

Tags: node.js, hashicorp-vault

I have my own vault server running remotely.
I want to access the vault and get the secrets after login.
**login method: GIT TOKEN**
also i don't know how to login using git token in nodejs
and **then i want to read a specific key:value pair**.

Thanks in advance for help

Answer (score 0):

Admin actions in Vault (with root or similar permissions):

```
$> vault secrets enable -path=secret/ kv
$> vault kv put secret/amit key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3
$> vault policy write amit-github-policy -<EOF
  path "secret/amit" {
    capabilities = ["read", "list"]
  }
  EOF
$> vault auth enable github
$> vault write auth/github/map/users/amit_rathod value=amit-github-policy
```

- for setting your secrets and policies you can use any method and approaches

After configuring the Vault you can first to be authenticated:

```
curl --request=POST --data='{"token": "<your GitHub token>"}' <VAULT_HOST>/v1/auth/github/login
```

You receive the answer

```
{
  "auth": {
    "renewable": true,
    "lease_duration": 2764800,
    "metadata": {
      "username": "amit_rathod"
    },
    "policies": ["default", "amit-github-policy"],
    "accessor": "f93c4b2d-18b6-2b50-7a32-0fecf88237b8",
    "client_token": "1977fceb-3bfa-6c71-4d1f-b64af98ac018"
  }
}
```

With received `client_token` you can get accessible secrets:

```
curl --header="X-Vault-Token: 1977fceb-3bfa-6c71-4d1f-b64af98ac018" --request=GET <VAULT_HOST>/v1/secret/amit
```

You will receive the response with json with your keys and values.

P.S. I used random values for this example:

- kv path: `secret/`
- kv secret: `secret/amit`
- secret values: `key1=value1 key2=value2 key3=value3`
- policy name: `amit-github-policy`
- GitHub user name: `amit_rathod`
- response token: `1977fceb-3bfa-6c71-4d1f-b64af98ac018`

Comment: What you are doing is working with cli, i want to get kv secret from nodejs application code, thanks.

Comment: If we need to perform some operations with Vault with high permissions, better to make them directly with Vault (read - through CLI). But nothing bothers you to perform all these operations with 'curl' and root permissions, the same order, just use HTTP API.

Comment: Thank you, brother it was really helpful i am going with this approach

Comment: is there a curl to fetch value for a specific key at secret/amit. for example i have two key pair value i.e name=amit surname=rathod so can i get specific name, is there any curl for that , thank you.

Comment: For CLI there id a field 'field' - https://www.vaultproject.io/docs/commands/kv/get/#inlinecode--field-29
For HTTP API I don't know. I think it must be. Try to use 
curl -H "X-Vault-Token: ..." -X GET http://.../secret/amit?field=key1

Comment: But I think it's not a good idea because if you set secret as json, the secret will contain only root keys of json. Example: {"key1": {"key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}}. You assume that you have 2 pairs in secret with keys 'key1.key2' and 'key1.key3', but really you have one key 'key1' and value {"key2": "value2", "key3": "value3"}.
Better take full secret and parse in in your NodeJS, it's not a problem.

Answer (score 0):

This is some code that is working for me!

```
const vault = require("node-vault")({
    apiVersion: "v1",
    endpoint: "yourHashiCorpVaultUrl",
  });
  
  const roleId = process.env.ROLE_ID;
  const secretId = process.env.SECRET_ID;

const run = async () => {
    const result = await vault.approleLogin({
        role_id: roleId,
        secret_id: secretId,
    });
    
    vault.token = result.auth.client_token;
    const { data : returnValue }  = await vault.read("pathOfSecret"); 
    const { data } = returnValue;
    const { keys } = data;
    console.log("myKeys", keys);
  };
  
  run();
```

Comment: Where do you get your roleId and secretId from?